# probability of having normal daughter

Tags: genetics, homework, hematology

> If  father has hemophilia, mother is a carrier of the disease, then
>   what is the probability of having a normal daughter ?

My question: Should the probability of having a daughter be also multiplied ? Should the answer be 0.5 or should it be 0.25 ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is ambiguous.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi umm..I am not able to understand how this is ambiguous.Could you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't understand what you mean by "Should the probability of having a daughter be multiplied?" But yes, the probability of having a normal daughter is 0.25, but she will be a carrier like her mother.

Let H represent normal allele for blood clotting (dominant); h represent allele for hemophilia, XY represent the male chromosomes and XX represent the female chromosomes.

Parental Phenotypes :

```
   Normal female(carrier) x Hemophiliac male
```

Parental Genotypes (2n) :

```
   X(H)X(h)         x     X(h)Y
```

Gametes (n) :

```
   X(H)     X(h)    x   X(h)     Y
```

Possible Outcomes :

X(H)X(h) - A normal female, carrier.

X(H)Y    - A normal male.

X(h)X(h) - A hemophiliac female.

X(h)Y    - A hemophiliac male.

So probability of having a normal daughter, that is X(H)X(h) is 0.25.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to write superscripts, so I put the alleles in parenthesis. Its usually written in superscript. Hope this helps. :)